# Uploathing con next y express

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, next.js

Hola tengo este error:

> POST http://localhost:3018/unauthorized 405 (Method not allowed)

Cuando intento subir un archivo a uploathing.. estoy usando express con next . este archivo es de mi **`next.js`**:

```
import { generateReactHelpers } from "@uploadthing/react/hooks"; import type { OurFileRouter } from "../../../api/src/routes/uploathing"; export const { useUploadThing, uploadFiles } = generateReactHelpers();
```

Y este es de express mi rute handler seguido de mi **`app.ts`**:

```
import { createUploadthing, type FileRouter } from "uploadthing/server";

const f = createUploadthing(); export const uploadRouter = { videoAndImage: f({ image: { maxFileSize: "4MB", maxFileCount: 4, }, video: { maxFileSize: "16MB", }, }).onUploadComplete((data) => { console.log("upload completed", data); }), } satisfies FileRouter;

export type OurFileRouter = typeof uploadRouter; server.use( "/api/uploadthing", createUploadthingExpressHandler({ router: uploadRouter, }) );
```

¿Alguna idea que pudo haber pasado?